# Ruby on Rails inheritance syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given this piece of Code:

```
 class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :article, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I understand that CreateComments inherits methods from Migration. But what is Migration to ActiveRecord? Compared to other languages, I could not find any member named Migration in the ActiveRecord class. So what does the `::` mean? What do you call Migration in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here actually `Migration` is a class and `ActiveRecord` is module (namespace). So definition is:

```
module ActiveRecord
    class Migration
        ....
    end
end
```

base definition of the class `Migration` is in the file `/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb`

so, in order to call class Migration, you should specify in which module it is, therefore you have `ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: module is similar to namespace in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` is a namespace, `Migration` is a class 
more information in documentation 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

wish it helps